# Como eu consigo usar o execute sp_executesql para executar uma consulta montada numa variável?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Eu aprendendo a usar cursores e estou tentando executar uma consulta que montei dentro de uma variável mas está dando o seguinte erro:

"***Mensagem 214, Nível 16, Estado 2, Procedimento sp_executesql, Linha 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.***"

Eu não estou conseguindo entender. Segue abaixo o código que eu montei.

'''

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @COLUNA VARCHAR(100), @COLUNAS VARCHAR(MAX), @CLONAR VARCHAR(MAX), @NovoId int, @Id 
    varchar(11);

    --- Inicializar a variavel
    SET @COLUNAS    = ''
    SET @NovoId     = ''
    SET @CLONAR     = ''
    SET @Id = '1234'

    --sempre declare que o cursor é do tipo LOCAL FAST_FORWARD.
    --Local diz que é o scopo da execuçao e FAST_FORWARD significa que ele so vai pra frente.
    DECLARE CURCOLUNAS CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE   TABLE_CATALOG   = 'MeuBanco'
            AND TABLE_SCHEMA= 'dbo'
            AND TABLE_NAME  = 'MinhaTabela'
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
    OPEN CURCOLUNAS
        FETCH NEXT FROM CURCOLUNAS INTO @COLUNA
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @COLUNAS = @COLUNAS + ',' + @COLUNA
            FETCH NEXT FROM CURCOLUNAS INTO @COLUNA --- O into nesta linha
        END

        SET @COLUNAS= Right(@COLUNAS, len(@COLUNAS)-1);
        SET @CLONAR = N'SELECT '+@COLUNAS+' FROM MinhaTabela WHERE Id = '+@Id;
        print @CLONAR;

        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MeuBanco].[dbo].[MinhaTabela] ON
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @CLONAR;
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MeuBanco].[dbo].[MinhaTabela] OFF

        --SET @NovoId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        --PRINT  @NovoId
    CLOSE CURCOLUNAS;
    DEALLOCATE CURCOLUNAS;
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viva, só precisas de alterar a variável @CLONAR para **NVARCHAR**, é o que o erro está a indicar..."...expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/**nvarchar**'."

```
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @COLUNA VARCHAR(100), @COLUNAS VARCHAR(MAX), @CLONAR NVARCHAR(MAX), @NovoId int, @Id 
    varchar(11);

    --- Inicializar a variavel
    SET @COLUNAS    = ''
    SET @NovoId     = ''
    SET @CLONAR     = ''
    SET @Id = '1234'

    --sempre declare que o cursor é do tipo LOCAL FAST_FORWARD.
    --Local diz que é o scopo da execuçao e FAST_FORWARD significa que ele so vai pra frente.
    DECLARE CURCOLUNAS CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE   TABLE_CATALOG   = 'MeuBanco'
            AND TABLE_SCHEMA= 'dbo'
            AND TABLE_NAME  = 'MinhaTabela'
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
    OPEN CURCOLUNAS
        FETCH NEXT FROM CURCOLUNAS INTO @COLUNA
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @COLUNAS = @COLUNAS + ',' + @COLUNA
            FETCH NEXT FROM CURCOLUNAS INTO @COLUNA --- O into nesta linha
        END

        SET @COLUNAS= Right(@COLUNAS, len(@COLUNAS)-1);
        SET @CLONAR = N'SELECT '+@COLUNAS+' FROM MinhaTabela WHERE Id = '+@Id;
        print @CLONAR;

        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MeuBanco].[dbo].[MinhaTabela] ON
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @CLONAR;
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MeuBanco].[dbo].[MinhaTabela] OFF

        --SET @NovoId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        --PRINT  @NovoId
    CLOSE CURCOLUNAS;
    DEALLOCATE CURCOLUNAS;
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Ernesto, agora vou tentar jogar esse resultado dentro de uma variável e copiar esse resultado para um registro novo na mesma tabela.